# How can I hide the "BRAND NEW" project in my portfolio?

Tags: wordpress, tags, project, portfolio, divi

I've built a project page on my website using wordpress and Divi supreme pro.

The first part is my 'NEW' project and it takes up the whole width.
The second part is a portfolio of all my projects.

The problem is that my "NEW" project is duplicated between the first part and the first project of my part 2.

I would like to hide the "New" project of the my portofolio. I did thing about using a tag on the "New" project only but now sure..?

Any help? Many thanks.

Comment: I cannot understand what your problem is. What is a "project"? Is this just a CSS thing you are trying to layout?

Comment: Alright, I did succeeed with this :

Comment: I did succeed with this code
.filter-portfolio
.project_category_a-la-une {
 display: none !important;
}

But I have now a new issue. Each line og the portfolio should have 3 items. Now I don't display the first one, I only have 2 item on the first line. How can I moove the item of the next line on this line ?

Comment: If the code in your comment solved your problem, and you think it would benefit others in the future, please post that as an answer. TBH, because none of us have your theme, nor will we ever, and the fix was to just hide something, I don't think it will be. If you don't think this will benefit others, I would recommend closing your question. Also, SO is generally a "one question at a time" site. If you have a new question, please post that as a new question.